# Gradient Descent to solve for Empirical Equation with 2 knowns and 2 unkowns

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, gradient-descent

I have the following empirical equation (engineering):

```
Y = A + (X  - B) * (0.3026506 * (A/B))^0.3895556 * (0.2444663 * (A/B))^1.226 + 0.00000560643 * A^(0.00125 * B + 0.3026)
```

Where I don't know values of A and B (but know that there are between some physical boundaries) and have the values of Y and X given me in a table format:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 179.92 |
| 40 | 181.46 |
| 50 | 184.53 |
| 60 | 187.61 |
| 70 | 190.69 |
| 90 | 196.84 |
| 100 | 199.92 |
| 110 | 203 |
| 120 | 206.08 |
| 130 | 209.16 |
| 140 | 212.23 |
| 150 | 215.31 |

My aim is to tweak the values of **A** and **B** such that the equation on the RHS will have similar values to **Y** in the table given all the constants given in the equation. One of my assumptions, is to use Gradient Descent for multivariate regression. I think I should take Y as my cost function, but how do I create gradient descent plot if I don't know what kind of values A and B should have? May be other approach is required? Basically, it is one equation with two knowns and two unkowns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you could do:

```
def error(par, X, Y):
    A = par[0]
    B = par[1]
    V = A + (X  - B) * (0.3026506 * (A/B))**0.3895556 * (0.2444663 * (A/B))**1.226 + 0.00000560643 * A**(0.00125 * B + 0.3026)
    return ((Y-V)**2).sum()

from scipy.optimize import minimize


X = [ 35,  40,  50,  60,  70,  90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]
Y = [179.92, 181.46, 184.53, 187.61, 190.69, 196.84, 199.92, 203.  ,
       206.08, 209.16, 212.23, 215.31]

minimize(error, [1,2], (X, Y))['x']
array([202.39468192, 108.03429635])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help;) 
In the error function we are defining R-squared error between the Y and the Right Hand Side of the equation, right?
Also, what kind of algorithm is used inside a scipy.optimize library? I went to the function website, but there are several algorithms and I don't know which one have you chosen

Comment: @Beginn_noo you can use any of the methods defined. i did not select the method so as you may decide on what method you want to use. just include the parameter `method='BFGS'` for example. Note that *If not given, chosen to be one of BFGS, L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, depending if the problem has constraints or bounds.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach using a linear regression.

[image]

Then this is no longer a problem of regression but a problem of solving the system of two equations for the two unknown A and B.

[image]

The problem is reduced to only one non-linear equation to be solved for B.

Using Newton-Raphson method the result is  B=108.0343

A=1.873431*108.0343=202.3947

Note that the non-linear equation is quasi-linear (second term quite neglibible = 0.0000573). So if you accept a sligthly lower accuracy, more simply use B=169.14586/1.565669=108.03424 which is very close to the Newton-Raphson result.

This means that you would obtain a very close approximation for A and B with the simpler equation : Y = A +(X-B) * 0.1116231 * (A/B)^1.6155556

Comment: Thanks very much for your comprehensive response, but why the equation is linear? I thought that this is bivariate non-linear equation case because I have two unknowns and there are several different exponents above the coefficients.

Thanks again for your response

Comment: OK. You are right. I was talking about the linearity of the function $Y(X)$. Of course the function is not linear wrt the parameters to be optimized. So, my sentence was confusing. In order to avoid more discussion, I delete the questionable part, which doesn't change the main part of the answer.